# listView.Selectedindeces[0] Unhandled exception

Tags: c#

I'm trying to locate the list item that a user selects in a ListView box, however, whenever I try to use listview.SelectedIndeces[0], I get an unhandled exception error stating "InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for "index"".

Here is the code:

```
    private void TabPage3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Child child in Children)
        {
            editChildListView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] {child.name, child.dob.ToString("dd/MM/yy"), child.comment }));
        }
        if (editChildListView.Items.Count >= 0)
        {
            int selectedIndex = editChildListView.SelectedIndices[0];
            editNameBox.Text = Children[selectedIndex].name;
        }
    }
```

ANSWER:

```
        private void EditChildListView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (editChildListView.Items.Count >= 0)
        {
            int selectedIndex = editChildListView.SelectedIndices[0];
            editNameBox.Text = Children[selectedIndex].name;
        }
    }
```

The method needed to be called from the listview_SelectedIndexChanged function rather than the tab3_Click function

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
 int selectedIndex = editChildListView.SelectedIndices.FirstOrDefault();
```

Then you won't get an error if nothing is selected.

You probably just want to check something is selected.